# Google Chrome library/api to interpret page and return page info

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, web-scraping

I basically need a way to programatically get "Inspect element" functionality of google chrome. I know chrome provides libraries and api's for different languages like JS and Java. What I am hoping to learn if is there an library/api with embedded browser functionality that might return me "Inspect element" which contains css, js and html all together.

What I am hoping to have at the end is something like that:

```
var chromeconnection = chrome.connect ("www.myurl.com");
var pageInfo = chromeconnection.getPageInfo();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Think Jaunt is what you are looking for

> HTML, XHTML, XML parsing. Protocols: HTTP, HTTPS, 
>   basic auth. Form
>   fill-out via field labels/names/sequence. 
>   Automatic form permutation.
>   File downloading/uploading.
>   **Saving complete web page (images, js, css, etc).
>   ** DOM navigation, search & search chaining. Regex-enabled querying. HTTP 
> header/cookie
>   manipulation. HTTP/HTTPS proxy support. 
>   Customizable caching & content
>   handlers. Pagination discovery. 
>   100% Java (no dependencies)

http://jaunt-api.com/

You have also selenium which has a very large community but i think it's too much for what you want to do

Comment: I think Jaunt might be able to do the task. But the library seems quite "under construction - the don't even have a maven import" so I have found a work-through.

Answer (score 0):

Chrome provides the [chrome.devtools.inspectedWindow](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/devtools_inspectedWindow) which it uses for the browser dev tools.

Description from the website:

> Use the chrome.devtools.inspectedWindow API to interact with the
>   inspected window: obtain the tab ID for the inspected page, evaluate
>   the code in the context of the inspected window, reload the page, or
>   obtain the list of resources within the page.

Sound exactly like the thing you need.

Comment: sorry I was going to say Inspect element functionality not the page info functionality. I edited the question.